# Adding Dynamic Content to an XML Document

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-xml, xelement

can you please help me with this code. Thank you.

In this code under the word Today a warning : **an embedded expression cannot be used here**

```
Dim doc = _
New XElement("Books", _
New XElement("Book", _
New XAttribute("ISBN", "0000000000001"), _
New XAttribute("RecordDate", <%= Today %>), _
New XElement("Price", 11.95), _
New XElement("Name", "Book Title 1"), _
New XElement("Stock", _
New XAttribute("InStock", 12), _
New XAttribute("OnOrder", 24))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to code like in asp.net, 
Try changing the usage as below:

`New XAttribute("RecordDate", DateTime.Today)`

If you want to use embedded expressions, you do not need to use Linq-to-xml construction using `new XAtrribute` etc. but you can do it directly constructiong the xml as show in this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384964%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Code in book "Visual Basic 2010" , Author: Evangelos Petroutsos, page 599. If you google it you can find this e-book.